# counting abscense or rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I need to write a stored procedures to update contacts who have no active pledges in our database, I can't seem to find a way of counting contacts with 0 rows on the pledges table.

The external key in the pledges table is supporter_id, I've tried using Count(*), but it only returns 1 or more.

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is on a MS SQL database.

Comment: Please provide the full query that you've tried so far, table structure would be nice, and sample data wouldn't hurt but in this case doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 2):

We'd need more information to give you a specific answer, but there are a number of ways to identify non-matching records, here are two:

LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM TableB b
                  WHERE a.ID = b.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended using a subquery so I first determine who has pledges of the type I want and then look for contacts who are not in that list.

thanks for the responses.